# Trying to change my input from string to list form

Tags: python

I have a code that works fine since it prints out sequences, but my input is supposed to be in this form `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]` but currently this is how my inputs are `(0111100111)`. What do I have to change?

```
import re


def sequences(input: str):
    chars = set(input)
    mxlength = 0
    output = ['not greater than 2']
    for i in chars:
        substrings = re.findall(f"{i}+", input)
        for substring in substrings:
            length = len(substring)

            if length > mxlength and length > 2:
                output = [substring, ]
                mxlength = length
            elif length == mxlength and length > 2:
                output.append(substring)
    return output


seq1 = sequences
print('This sequences is :', seq1('0110101100'))
print('This sequences is :', seq1("1110001100"))
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, in my humble opinion.

Comment: If you really need to work with a list of integers, then a fairly big rewrite is in order, because regular expressions won't help.  Of course, regular expressions are a terrible way to solve this problem, anyway.  Are you supposed to return the  length of the longest series of identical digits?

Comment: rename `input` to `array`, and pass `list('0110101100')` in `seq1`

Comment: @TimRoberts i am supposed to return a sequence greater than 2 the code does that but I found out I am supposed to have the inputs in list form

Comment: If you want to turn `input = '0110101100'` to a list of zeroes and ones, do `output = [int(c) for c in input]`.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is an array of numbers, you can convert it to a string using `input = "".join(map(str,input))` and then use your existing code.  (by the way `input` is a Python keyword, you should not use it as a variable or parameter name)

You could also use groupby to process the data without regular expressions:

```
from itertools import groupby
def sequences(s):
    seqs = ["".join(map(str,g)) for _,(*g,) in groupby(s) if len(g)>2]
    return seqs or 'not greater than 2'
```

output:

```
sequences([1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])  # ['111', '000']

# also works with a str input:

sequences('1110001100')           # ['111', '000']
sequences('0110101100')           # 'not greater than 2'
```

*[EDIT]*

If what you're trying to get it the longest sequence of each value (that is larger than 2), you can create a dictionary from the groups sorted by size to keep only the largest group of each value:

```
def sequences(s):
    groups = [g for _,(*g,) in groupby(s) if len(g)>2]
    seqs   = { g[0]:"".join(map(str,g)) for g in sorted(groups,key=len) }
    return list(seqs.values()) or 'not greater than 2'
```